Apache Beam transform "Latest.CombineFn()" fails when trying to get latest record from windowed PCollection<Row> with timestamps Row records
I have a very simple use case
I have a windowed PCollection with timestamps, I am applying following transformation
Group.byFieldNames("field1", "field2").aggregateField("Field3",Latest.combineFn(),"latestField3")
This fails with following error , running on DirectRunner
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find field type for T
Appreciate any help to resolve this issue!!
Thanks
Ritesh
Sample Code
`package com.example;

import com.example.schema.TestRecord;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.StreamingOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.NoSuchSchemaException;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.FixedWindows;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.Window;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.Group;

import org.joda.time.Instant;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class App {
    public interface Options extends StreamingOptions {
        @Description("Input text to print.")
        @Default.String("My input text")
        String getInputText();

        void setInputText(String value);
    }




    public static PCollection<Row> buildPipeline(Pipeline pipeline, String inputText) {

        PCollection<String> input =
                pipeline.apply(
                        Create.of("{" +
                                "\"count\":1," +
                                "\"timestamp\":1660149636076," +
                                "\"store_id\":\"1\"," +
                                "\"product_id\":\"10050\"" +
                                "}",
                                "{" +
                                        "\"count\":1," +
                                        "\"timestamp\":1660149637076," +
                                        "\"store_id\":\"1\"," +
                                        "\"product_id\":\"10050\"" +
                                        "}",
                                "{" +
                                        "\"count\":1," +
                                        "\"timestamp\":1660149638076," +
                                        "\"store_id\":\"1\"," +
                                        "\"product_id\":\"10050\"" +
                                        "}",
                                "{" +
                                        "\"count\":80," +
                                        "\"timestamp\":1660149638076," +
                                        "\"store_id\":\"1\"," +
                                        "\"product_id\":\"10050\"" +
                                        "}"

                        ));
        Schema testRecordSchema;

        try {
             testRecordSchema = input.getPipeline().getSchemaRegistry().getSchema(TestRecord.class);
        } catch (NoSuchSchemaException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        PCollection<Row> inventory =
                input.apply(JsonToRow.withSchema(testRecordSchema));

        inventory.apply(ParDo.of(new Print<>("inventory<Row> is: ")));

        PCollection<Row> inventoryWithTime =  inventory.apply(WithTimestamps.of( (Row row) -> {
            assert row != null;
            return new Instant(row.getValue("timestamp"));
        }));



        inventoryWithTime.apply(ParDo.of(new Print<>("inventoryWithTime<Row> is: ")));

        PCollection<Row> inventoryWithTimeAndWindow = inventoryWithTime.apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(6))));
        inventoryWithTimeAndWindow.apply(ParDo.of(new Print<>("inventoryWithTimeAndWindow<Row> is: ")));

        return inventoryWithTimeAndWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
        var pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<Row> windowedCollection = App.buildPipeline(pipeline, options.getInputText());

// This works fine, if window is not applied

        //PCollection<Row> windowedCollection_0 = windowedCollection.apply(Combine.globally());

        //windowedCollection_0.apply(ParDo.of(new Print<>("windowedCollection_0<Row> is: ")));

        // Below works, and could be an alternative to Latest.CombineFn()
//      PCollection<Row> windowedCollection_1 = windowedCollection.apply(
//              Group.<Row>byFieldNames("product_id", "store_id", "count")
//                      .aggregateField("timestamp",Max.ofLongs(), "latestCount"));

// Below does not work

        PCollection<Row> windowedCollection_1 = windowedCollection.apply(Group.<Row>byFieldNames("product_id", "store_id")
                .aggregateField("count", Latest.combineFn(),"latest_count"));

        windowedCollection_1.apply(ParDo.of(new Print<>("windowedCollection_1<Row> is: ")));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }


    static class Print<T> extends DoFn<T, String> {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Print.class);
        String message;

        public Print(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void process(@Element T row) throws IOException {

            LOG.info(message + row.toString());

        }
    }

}
`

I have tried alternative method of getting latest records as shown in commented portion of sample code i.e. use max.oflongs for timestamp attribute from Row. It works but I dont like this solution as I have to keep my desired attribute "count" in key , and then I can not use Double or Float type with count, limiting usage of my solution
